# What website can I go in which I can find people that discuss Window-style OS improvements?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

This is more of a hobby of mine that I've been working on for the past 5 years.  I'd like to find a group of people that I can discuss innovative ideas that would be a major improvement to the current windows-style OS that everyone uses.  I hate it and I think there has got to be something better than what was made decades ago.

I'd like to bring a few minds together, throw out some ideas to each other, discuss them, and finally end with something fabulously new and innovative.  Something on the scale of how the mouse was an improvement on the CLI of MS-DOS.  Shock consumers on how much easier it is to use.

Are we really still at the point of organizing data in folders?  And, folder in folders?

Comment: None of the SE sites are open for these type of discussions.

Comment: For OS suggestion for Windows only the feedback hub exist as the official's way; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites, not necessarily *discussion* sites.* As a result, there are no sites on the network that would permit loose discussion on a topic.

Software Engineering.SE has an [operating-systems tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems), in which questions about the basic tasks an electronic device should perform are on-topic. If you have questions about how an operating system performs any of these tasks, I would ask there. Be sure to read their [on-topic guidance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), though.

There are also no Stack Exchange sites that would allow you to gather people together and create a product. SE sites are focused on clear, concise questions about their related topics, and offer a place for your well-researched question to get a similarly well-researched answer.

During your venture in OS innovation, if you happen to run into a knowledge roadblock, Software Engineering may be for you. Otherwise, I'm afraid no site is capable of handling your needs.

<sub>*Meta sites have [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tags, but those are to discuss various issues on their parent site.</sub>